# Cloudstack launch instance error when trying to assign storage

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I installed Cloudstack 4.11.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

This is my environment:

- 1 Zone
- 1 Pod
- 2 Clusters (LXC and KVM)
- 2 Hosts (one in each cluster)

i can launch perfectly VMs on the KVM cluster but when i'm trying to launch a new instance with an LXC template i'm getting that the instance couldn't be deployed

I already have configured the secondary and primary storage on the environment. And when the instance is been deployed i see it gets allocated CPU and RAM from the LXC host. The issue is when the storage allocation process is been made, it can't find any storage pool. This problem isn't happening when i launch a new instance in the KVM cluster
I attach here the log of the process.

```
2019-06-12 09:02:45,500 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.LocalStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) LocalStoragePoolAllocator trying to find storage pool to fit the vm
2019-06-12 09:02:45,500 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.ClusterScopeStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) ClusterScopeStoragePoolAllocator looking for storage pool
2019-06-12 09:02:45,500 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.ClusterScopeStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) Looking for pools in dc: 1  pod:1  cluster:2. Disabled pools will be ignored.
2019-06-12 09:02:45,500 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.ClusterScopeStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) Found pools matching tags: []
2019-06-12 09:02:45,501 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.ClusterScopeStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) No storage pools available for shared volume allocation, returning
2019-06-12 09:02:45,501 DEBUG [o.a.c.s.a.ZoneWideStoragePoolAllocator] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) ZoneWideStoragePoolAllocator to find storage pool
2019-06-12 09:02:45,503 DEBUG [c.c.d.DeploymentPlanningManagerImpl] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) No suitable pools found for volume: Vol[24|vm=14|ROOT] under cluster: 2
2019-06-12 09:02:45,503 DEBUG [c.c.d.DeploymentPlanningManagerImpl] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) No suitable pools found
2019-06-12 09:02:45,503 DEBUG [c.c.d.DeploymentPlanningManagerImpl] (API-Job-Executor-26:ctx-9fa50775 job-67 ctx-624410ca) (logid:8eddb393) No suitable storagePools found under this Cluster: 2
```

This is the instance creation related content on the  [cloudstack-management.log](https://pastebin.com/HHKnHi36)

Answer (score 0):

how do you have your storage pools configured? per cluster or zone-wide?

if it's per cluster you may not have pools on the lxc cluster.